# Passing variable to webelement defined with annotation in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, variables, annotations, element

I use annotations to declare webelement in selenium java.
In most of the cases i have simple locator:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using="login")
WebElement btnLogin;

public void clickLogin() {
        btnLogin.click()
    }
```

But then there are sometimes cases when I need to pass variable into xpath or any other locator.
In this situation I do that without declaring webelement before but in the function instead:

```
 public void clickElement(String elementName) {
         driver.findElementByXpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='" + elementName + "']")
    }
```

**I dont like it because locators should be called before in one place and not mixed with functions for code visibility**

I thought of doing something like this:

```
String elementXpathPrePart= "//android.widget.TextView[@text='";
String elementXpathPostPart = "']";
```

and then

```
public void clickElement(String elementName) {
             driver.findElementByXpath(elementXpathPrePart + elementName + elementXpathPostPart )
        }
```

**Do you have any solution for this?**

Comment: Annotations values cannot be evaluated in runtime. Probably there could be some workarounds on the level of where selenium parses this `By` value from annotation. However it is not really clear how you would use such parameterization if you would have one. Assume you can put a parameter to your annotation. How and where you would give the value for that prameter?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a common issue in the Page object model when you are using the page factory. Solutions for this:

1. Use constants,java file and keep all xpaths there are refer from there

   public class Constants{
   public static final String myxpath="//input[@id='username']
   }
   In-Page class:

   @FindBy(how = How.ID, using=Constants.myxpath)
   WebElement btnLogin;

OR

In code

```
public void clickElement(String elementName) {
             driver.findElementByXpath(By. xpath(Constants.myxpath ).click()
        }
```